# How to setup layouts in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-4

[By example](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#controller-layouts) I'm trying to create the layout. My base controller looks like this:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
    protected $layout = 'layouts.default';
}
```

Then i extend it via user controller like which looks like this:

```
namespace Site;

use View;

class UserController extends \BaseController {
    
    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('site/user/index');
        // return View::make('site/user/index');
    }
}
```

But in the end I get the following error `Attempt to assign property of non-object`. `var_dump` shows that `$this->layout` is the string, not the object.

Basically i just want to do `return View::make('site/user/index');`.

Comment: does /views/site/user/index.blade.php exist?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange yap, `return View::make('site/user/index');` makes html, but without layout.

Comment: does /views/layouts/default.blade.php exist?

Comment: I believe when you use `$this->layout->content`, it would be setting the `content` section in your `layouts.default` template.  Do you have a `@yield('content')` item in `layouts/default.blade.php`?

Comment: @user3158900 yap, it is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I prefer to do layouts.

Firstly - I DONT set `protected $layout = 'layouts.default';` in the controller - I just leave it out.

Second - I setup a template like this:

**app/views/layouts/master.blade.php**

```
<h1>This is my master template</h1>

@yield('content')

<h5>This is my footer</h5>
```

Then in my various views

**app/views/user/index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    This is the user section
@stop
```

This way the layout template is defined in the view, not the controller, which is where I think it should be (the controller shouldnt know/care about what template your view uses).

Comment: yeah, it's true, but I'm wondering why the example doesn't work ?

Comment: Yeah - not sure - maybe someone else can help. Looks like it should work

Comment: blade layouts are much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all your blades are OK and you insist using Controller layout because Laravel allow it as an option, add this snippet to your `BaseController` to fix that:

```
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 5, you can do it like this (I am not sure if it is the best way)

```
return view("layout/here", [
    "content" => view("dynamic/content/here")
]);
```

then in your view you can do this

```
 <?php echo $content; ?>
```

of course, if you are not using blade.

Comment: Your solution is "handy" but can't handle the DRY principle (set just one time in the controller the right layout) from laravel 4.